# Node-red syntax error "Cannot find name 'document'" using function node

Tags: node-red

I'm getting a syntax error while in the function node code editor (red underline squiggles and triangle):

```
const puppeteer = global.get('puppeteer');

(async () =>
{
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium'});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('http://church.daford.work:58080', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  await page.type('#password', 'pwd-here');
  await page.click('#loginBtn');
  // @ts-ignore
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);
  console.log(data);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

```
Cannot find name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library?
Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to include 'dom'.(2584)
```

Where do I do this?

UPDATE: I found I can ignore this error with

```
// @ts-ignore
```

and the code works, but I would like to know if there is a better way  to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you running this code? If this is inside a Node-RED Function node, then that code runs inside a node.js environment, not the browser. This means there is no `document` object to work with.

If this is somewhere else in Node-RED, please update your question with full details.